# How to prove that the first derivative of $ \left| ln(x) \right| $ exists?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I am trying to prove that the first derivative of $ \left| ln(x) \right| $ exists.

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_o-h) -f(x_0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln(x_o-h) -\ln(x_0)}{h}   =  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln(\frac{x_o-h}{x_0})}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln(1 -\frac{h}{x_0})}{h} \quad (1) $$

But I don't know how to continue this.

Any ideas (without D'Hopital on limits)?

Comment: What's your definition of natural logarithm?  There's a different answer depending on what your definition is.

Comment: Your question is with an absolute value, but not your resolution.

Comment: What are you "allowed" to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiation is a local property, as we are computing limits to a certain point. Note that if $x_0\in(0,1)$, then $|\ln(x)|=-\ln(x)$ in a small interval around there, so $|\ln(t)|$ is differentiable there. Likewise if $x_0>1$ (it will be $|\ln(x)|=\ln(x)$ in a small interval around $x_0$, so it will be differentiable at $x_0$. But on $x_0=1$, your function is not differentiable and I leave this as an exercise to you! (hint: look at the other answer)

Comment: You don't prove differentiability of a function by saying that it is differentiable, do you ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust OP clearly knows that $\ln$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. The point of my answer is that I'm specifying that differentiation is a local property, so we may look what happens around each point separately. This is also why I point out that we have a problem around point $1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust So they are asking questions about Laplace's transform but do not know that $\ln$ is differentiable. They have learned about DLH, but have not learned that $\ln$ is differentiable. I highly doubt that.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and comments. They've all been very valuable tbh.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Laplace transforms appears on other recent posts by this user. Anyway, I gladly accept criticism; apparently op finds my answer (as well as Kavi's) helpful, so I don't think there's anything else to discuss here

Comment: I posted an algebraic proof. I'll keep this answer accepted because it helped me get unstuck.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true. The function is defined on $(0,\infty)$ and it is not differentiable at $1$. This is because the left hand derivative at $1$ is $-1$ and the right hand derivative is $+1$. The function is differentiable at all points other than $1$.

[Note that the function is $\ln x$ for $x >1$ and $-\ln x$ for $x<1$].

Answer (score 1):

$\left| ln(x) \right| =  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      -ln(x),&\forall x \in (0,1) \\
      ln(x), &\forall x \in (1,+\infty)\\
\end{array} 
\right.  $

It is obvious that $\forall x \in (0,+\infty) - \{1\}$ the function is differentiable as a logarithmic function.

For $x_0 \to 1^-$:

$f'(x) = (-\ln(x))^{'}) = - \frac{1}{x_0} = -1$

For $x_0 \to 1^+$:

$f'(x) = (\ln(x))^{'}) = - \frac{1}{x_0} = 1$

Therefore, the limit (derivative definition) doesn't exist. Therefore the function is non-differentiable at $x_0=1$

At last, the answer is: $f(x)$ is differentiable  $\forall x \in (0,+\infty) - \{1\}$

---

An intuitive explanation of this would be to draw the two tagnent lines of $f(x)$ at $x_0$ i.e

$$ y = (-1)(x-1)$$
$$ y = (1)(x-1)$$
[image]